# AJV is not validating my schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, ajv

I am facing problem regarding AJV Schema Validator.
I have following schema

```
{
    "$id": "create-offer.json#",
    "body": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "statusCode": {
                "type": "number"
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "type": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "routePlanId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "currencyId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "autoRateUpdateActive": {
                "type": "boolean"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my response is :

```
{ statusCode: 2006,
  statusPhrase: 'Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SPHERE_D1.CHECK_UNIQUE_RATE_NAME) violated\nORA-06512: at "SPHERE_D1.PKG_RATE_TABLES_V2", line 102\nORA-06512: at "SPHERE_D1.PKG_RATE_TABLES_V2", line 54\nORA-06512: at line 1' }
```

Using the following code to validate :

```
let valid = ajv.validate(schema, res);
var detailedErrorMsg = "\n" + ajv.errorsText(ajv.errors, { separator: "\n" }) + "\n";
console.log(detailedErrorMsg);
```

AJV should return error as schema and response are different, but AJV is returning 'no errors'. 
Is there any problem with the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved by adding required feilds in schema definition.

```
{
    "$id": "create-offer.json#",
    "description": "",
    "title": "",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        /*mention objects which should be requird*/
    ]
}
```